# Java generic with return type that has @NonNull with Collections

Tags: java, generics, non-nullable

I want to implement a generic function in Java8, that verifies that a collection has no null members and returns a type with @NonNull annotation.

input type: T extends Collection, where T+U are nullable.
result type: @NonNull T, with @NonNull U

For array this would look like this:

```
public static <T> @NonNull T @NonNull[] arrayHasNoNullMember( @Nullable T @Nullable[] value) {
```

But for the collection case, i don't know how to define that the result type is the same as the input type, but has the @NonNull annotations for the collection and the element type.
This is what i want to do, but it is not valid syntax:

```
public static <T extends Collection<U>, U> @NonNull T<@NonNull U> collectionHasNoNullMember(T<U> col) {
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way in Java to alter a generic type parameter of a generic type, like the `U` in `T extends Collection<U>`. The equivalent of your array method would be a method that takes and returns Collection instances, like so:

```
public static <E> @NonNull Collection<@NonNull E> collectionHasNoNullMember(@Nullable Collection<? extends @Nullable E> col)
```

This accepts any subclass of Collection, but the return type can't be more specific than Collection.

To handle more specific cases, I would suggest having a few more methods for common subclasses:

```
public static <E> @NonNull List<@NonNull E> listHasNoNullMember(@Nullable List<? extends @Nullable E> list)
public static <E> @NonNull Set<@NonNull E> setHasNoNullMember(@Nullable Set<? extends @Nullable E> set)
public static <E> @NonNull Queue<@NonNull E> queueHasNoNullMember(@Nullable Queue<? extends @Nullable E> queue)
```

Or, as long as you're returning the same object, you can always manually cast it back to its actual class:

```
ArrayList<@NonNull E> list2 = (ArrayList<@NonNull E>) collectionHasNoNullMember(arrayList);
```

Comment: I would vote for the first approach (exact type Collection). Only for the (rare?) case that you really need to know the precise kind of collection afterwards, unfolding this into separate methods per collection type seem adequate.

Comment: Which library is providing this NonNull annotation?

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as you can get:

```
public static <T extends Collection<@NonNull U>, U> @NonNull T collectionHasNoNullMember(@NonNull T col) {
```

Comment: So there is no chance to get the @NonNull at all?

Comment: You can slip it in before the return type and before the parameter type, if that annotation is configured for TYPE_USE. Worth a try.

Comment: The point here is, that the parameter does not have @ NonNull for the collection and not for its elements type. And in the return both shall have it. Yes, @ NonNull is made for TYPE_USE.

Comment: My mistake then, you can use it on all of the parameters in that case.

Comment: I am asking for the container and the elements. Here it seems to get impossible, to have the input elements @ Nullable and the result elements to be @ NonNull.

Comment: Yeah java generics aren't expressive enough to communicate that, but your code can still function just fine, and you can document it accordingly. Generics was added late in java's life, so it can't quite compare with a language that has deep support of it from the beginning.